# Java Beans instantiating wrong bean

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

In my Spring-Module.xml I have two beans:

```
<bean id="two_num" class="main.java.com.shen.Generator">
    <property name="length" value="8" />
    <property name="categories" value="3" />
    ...
</bean>
<bean id="six_num" class="main.java.com.shen.Generator">
    <property name="length" value="6" />
    <property name="categories" value="1" />
    <property name="numeric" value="numeric" />
    ...
</bean>
```

And I instantiate my class like so:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");
    Generator obj = (Generator) context.getBean("two_num");
```

For some reasons, java is always instantiating my second bean despite me explicitly saying that I want the bean "two_num". If I were to flip the order around, and have "six_num"'s bean above "two_num", it would get the bottom bean. :| What's going on? I'm so confused. Is my method for selecting a specific bean wrong?

EDIT: after adding one more bean to it this is what I get when I run my program:

> > > INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@e949f69: defining beans [two_num,six_num,four_num]; root of factory hierarchy

And as expected, when I call a print method in my class, I can see that the current object is instantiated with the information dicated in four_num, and not "two_num"

Comment: what does the class Generator look like?

Comment: @vcetinick The class is pretty exentsive, but basically it has a few private variables, no constructor. And it has the setLength, setCategories, setNumeric methods.

Comment: are any of those variables static or final?

Comment: @vcetinick they are private static. But the issue is that even though I explicitly tell it I want to use the bean "two_num" it still uses a different one.

Comment: The fact the variables are static means that they are shared across all instances of that class, so it would mean that spring would set the same variables 3 times overrided each time and only remembering the last value set

Comment: @vcetinick is there no way to tell spring, I only want to instantiate it once, and that's using with bean id: x

Comment: is there a reason why the variables are static?

Comment: Could you declare your beans tag with default-lazy-init="true"? That /might/ help

Comment: @vcetinick come to think of it no... But I see what's going on now. Spring will instantiate every single bean. That's interesting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, I can only assume that the Generator class looks something like this

```
public class Generator {
  private static length;
  private static categories;

  //getters/setters
}
```

Given that i dont have a full class to work with, i can only recommend removing the static modifier as it would contradict the way you want to use the class.

Comment: Yes, th is is exactly the issue, I removed the static and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Certainly remove static modifiers on your fields, as already suggested.
Also, if you want 'singletons' modify your XML:

```
<bean id="two_num" class="main.java.com.shen.Generator" scope="singleton">
  <property name="length" value="8" />
  <property name="categories" value="3" />
  ...
</bean>
```

So you'll only get a single instance of each bean. You'll still get multiple instances of Generator, but only one per bean.